# Styling specific ui-selectonemenu-list-item

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I have a selectOneMenu with a styleclass.

Can someone write me how to style the items inside?

I'm trying to access them via styleclass.

I can change the stylings general by doing

`.ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper {font-size:13px;}`

however it doesn't work via a styleClass which I have added to the selectOneMenu

```
<p:selectOneMenu styleClass="someClass"...
```

It wont work like this:

```
.someClass .ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper {
    font-size:13px;}
```

Comment: Css works on the client-side html and there is no html in your question. Effectivley it is not even an html or PrimFaces issue but most likely a pure css one the 'needs' the html. I'm inclied to vote to close this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles and the wrapper and working css selector is no related to a specific item, just the wrapper

Comment: Your style maybe is overridden by pf one, so be more specific, try with your browser developer tool,